# ESP32 "ESPAsyncWebServer" PUT Json

Tags: json, webserver, esp32, put

I have a problem with ESP32 "ESPAsyncWebServer" PUT Json. There is an error in the code. How to fix it?

JavaScript Working:

```
async function test() {
  var val = JSON.stringify({on: ledState});
  xmlHttp.open("GET", "/test?json="+val, true);
  xmlHttp.send();
}
```

JavaScript Does not work:

```
async function led() {
  var val = JSON.stringify({on: ledState});
  try {
    const response = await fetch("/led", {
      method: "PUT",
      body: val,
      headers: {"Content-Type": "text/plain"}
    });
  } catch (error) {console.log("Request Failed: " + error);}
}
```

Web Server Working:

```
server.on("/test", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
  if (startuart) Serial.println("led");
  if (request->hasParam("json")) {
    String val = request->getParam("json")->value();
    if (startuart) Serial.println(val);
    request->send(200, "text/plain", "OK");
  } else {
    if (startuart) Serial.println("No Json!");
    request->send(200, "text/plain", "No Json!\n");
  }
});
```

Web Server Does not work:

```
server.on("/led", HTTP_PUT, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
  if (startuart) Serial.println("led");
  if (request->hasParam("body")) {
    String val = request->getParam("body")->value().c_str();  // value().c_str();
    if (startuart) Serial.println(val);
    request->send(200, "text/plain", "OK");
  } else {
    if (startuart) Serial.println("No Json!");
    request->send(200, "text/plain", "No Json!\n");
  }
});
```

**server.on("/led", HTTP_PUT, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request)**

It works, but the answer "No Json!" is displayed.

Comment: Why are you setting the content type to "text/plain" if you're trying to send JSON?

Comment: I changed to

headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

the result is the same.

Comment: For ESPAsyncWebServer POST and PUT request, the API should be `server.on("/led", HTTP_PUT, requestHandler, uploadHandler, bodyHandler)`, see the API [function prototype](https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer/blob/master/src/ESPAsyncWebServer.h#L426), all the three callbacks are defined as virtual and you need to implement it even you are not using it (e.g. uploadHandler) with just an empty function implementation. The [bodyHandler](https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer/blob/master/src/ESPAsyncWebServer.h#L395) gives you the necessary data to parse the body.

Comment: I have a project which show how to use ESPAsyncWebServer [POST request](https://github.com/e-tinkers/esp32_ir_remote/blob/master/src/main.cpp#L113), and how to  implement the [bodyHander](https://github.com/e-tinkers/esp32_ir_remote/blob/master/src/main.cpp#L73-L92).

Comment: hcheung, your example helped me. Thank you.